# Acquire lock when leaving WaitOne

Tags: c#, locking, atomic

I have a task scheduler implemented like this :

```
  private readonly List<Task> mTasks = new List<Task>();
  private readonly ManualResetEvent mNoTaskEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

  public void AddTask(Task task)
  {
     lock (mTasks)
     {
        mTasks.Add(task);
        mNoTaskEvent.Set();
     }
  }

  public void RemoveTask(Task task)
  {
     lock (mTasks)
     {
        mTasks.Remove(task);
        if (mTasks.Count == 0)
           mNoTaskEvent.Reset();
     }
  }

  void BackgroundThreadProc()
  {
     while (mRunning)
     {
        mNoTaskEvent.WaitOne();

        if (!mRunning) break;

        Task nextTask;

        lock (mTasks)
        {
           mTasks.Sort(...);
           nextTask = mTasks.First();
        }

        nextTask.Run();
     }
  }
```

mNoTaskEvent allows to block the background thread when there is no task available.
There is a race condition, if another thread remove all remaining tasks between "mNoTaskEvent.WaitOne()" and "lock (mTasks)".

How could I atomically acquire the mTasks lock when leaving mNoTaskEvent.WaitOne() ?

**Edit**
The pthread API has a function that does exactly what I need : [pthread_cond_wait](http://cursuri.cs.pub.ro/~apc/2003/resources/pthreads/uguide/users-78.htm#285729)

Comment: Have you looked at `Monitor.Wait()` for this?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't see how it could help me, you have an idea ?

Comment: It would replace the ResetEvent, not augment it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple fix for the race-condition would be to check the count again:

```
    lock (mTasks)
    {
       if (mTasks.Count < 1)
         continue;

       mTasks.Sort(...);
       nextTask = mTasks.First();
    }
```

---

Using Monitor.Wait():

```
 while (mRunning)
 {
    //mNoTaskEvent.WaitOne();

    if (!mRunning) break;

    Task nextTask;

    lock (mTasks)
    {
        while (mTasks.Count < 1)
        {
           Monitor.Wait(mTasks);

           if (!mRunning) break;                
        }

        ...     
    }



public void AddTask(Task task)
{
  lock (mTasks)
  {
     mTasks.Add(task);
     //mNoTaskEvent.Set();
     Monitor.Pulse(mTasks);
  }
}
```

You would also need to Pulse() when stopping the whole chain.

Comment: Yeah sure :-), but the goal of this question is more to find an elegant solution to the overall problem than to this actual case.

Comment: I'm not sure an "elegant solution to the overall problem" exists.

Comment: I was looking for something like the C function "pthread_cond_wait" which does [1] Release an owned mutex and wait on condition, [2] Wake-up and acquire the mutex, 1 & 2 being atomic. Your solution with the monitor is pretty nice, thanks !